# Advance for reference variables?

Tags: java, variables, object, reference

I am trying to understand the difference between Object with primitive variables when using them as parameters in a method.

There are some examples using reference variables:

```
public class Test1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] value = {1};
        modify(value);
        System.out.println(value[0]);
    }

    public static void modify(int[] v) {
        v[0] = 5;
    }
}
```

---

**result**: 5

```
public class Test2 {

    public static void main(String agrs[]) {
        Integer j = new Integer(1);
        refer(j);
        System.out.println(j.intValue());
    }

    public static void refer(Integer i) {
        i = new Integer(2);
        System.out.println(i.intValue());
    }
}
```

**result**: 2 | 1

So what is different in here?

Comment: What do you mean by "primary variables"? The main difference here is just that you're using an array in the first version...

Comment: In second example i using wrapper of primary variable, result is the same if i using i, j as primary. So i don't clear in this case. Any idea ?

Comment: @Thangnv It's called *primitive* variable.

Comment: There are no relevant primitive values in evidence here. What the OP means by it remains a mystery.

Answer (score 5):

Recall that the array *references* are passed by value. The array itself is an object, and that's not passed at all (That means that if you pass an array as an argument, your'e actually passing its memory address location).

In `modify()` method, you're assigning `5` to the first place in the array, hence, changing the array's value. So when you print the result, you get: `5` because the value has been changed.

In the second case, you're creating a *new Object* of type `Integer` locally. `i` will have the same value when you exit the method `refer()`. Inside it you print `2`, then you print `i`, which is `1` and hence change doesn't reflect.

Comment: Downvoter.. please explain so I can learn from my mistakes. Thanks.

Comment: Don't use the words "pass by reference," they have a precise meaning and don't apply to Java.

Comment: Exactly what Joni said. Anyone who understands what "pass by reference" *really* means will be very confused by that. Java uses pass by value for *all* arguments - it's just that the value of a reference type expression is a reference, not an object.

Comment: I didn't know that might cause this confusion since I explained it. Anyway, edited. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: @JonSkeet -- Yes got it clearly now, but many books write that java use pass by value for basic types, else pass by reference.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: Some do, yes. This is unfortunate, and incorrect. I wish authors would pay particular attention to accuracy - I get very cross with them for not doing so :( I would still adjust your first paragraph though, to say that the array *references* are passed by value. The array itself is an object, and that's not passed at all.

Answer (score 5):

In java array is primitive type.and Integer is Object type.

For primitives it is pass by value the actual value (e.g. 3)

For Objects you pass by value the reference to the object.

In first example,
you are changing value in array.

while in other example ,
you are changing reference of i to other memory location where object value is 2.
when returning back to main function, as you are not returning value. its reference scope limited to "refer" method only.

Answer (score 3):

`v[0] = 5`, is like saying `Get 0th element of current v's reference and make it 5.`
`i = new Integer(2)`, is like saying `change i to 2's Integer object reference`

In one case you are changing the internal values via the reference and in latter you are changing the reference itself.

Answer (score 2):

The difference here is that they are different.

In your first example you are passing the argument to another method, which is modifying one of its *elements,* which is visible at the caller. In the second case you are *assigning* the *variable* to a new value, which isn't visible at the caller, because Java has pass-by-value semantics.

NB 'Primary variable' has no meaning in Java.

I don't know what the word 'advance' in your title has to do with anything.

Comment: Advance - So, exactly i want to understand pass-by-value and pass-by-reference. Do you give me some doc or link helpfull ? thanks!

Comment: You still haven't explained what 'advance' is supposed to mean here. It's not a technical term in Java, and it doesn't have any other apparent relevance. You also haven't explained what you mean by 'primary' either. You could always try the Language Specification, or the book *The Java Programming Language*, just like everybody else did.

Comment: @Thangnv, EJP: I like [Ivor Horton's Beginning Java 2](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/productCd-0764568744.html) I don't know Java very much but I learned Core-Java.